# Why is my iOS App Associated Domain endpoint not being called by Apple?

Tags: ios, passwords, autofill, apple-app-site-associate

Following Apple's Password autofill guidelines with App Associated Domains [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains), I added the apple-app-site-association json file.

My app has that site listed as `webcredentials:example.com`. My app's bundle id is `com.app.App`  which is listed as one of the apps under webcredentials.apps. The site has an SSL certificate.

In my iOS app I have an email text field with a content type of `email` (I've also tried `username`) and I have a password text field with `new password` (I've also tried `password`). When I select the email text field I get suggested emails. But when I select the password text field I get the same email QuickType suggestions and I get an error in the console:

`Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.app.App due to error: Cannot save passwords for this app. Make sure you have set up Associated Domains for your app and AutoFill Passwords is enabled in Settings`

I have AutoFill Passwords enabled on my device and I've proved that it does work on other apps.

I also never see in the logs that apple is calling my endpoint I provided above.

I verified that my Apple team ID is correct.

I've run out of ideas. Can someone else see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**Update**:

It works fine on the simulator. The request goes out and the server gets it and it works. On the device it does NOT work.

I turned off the phone and turned it back on and it's working just fine... Really frustrating, I have no idea why it wasn't working, but I do know it was NOT making the network request from the device at all.

Answer (score 1):

I turned off the phone I was testing with and turned it back on and that somehow fixed it...  I have no idea why it wasn't working, but I do know it was NOT making the network request from the device at all.